# When the virtual member functions of a template class instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates

I know that the normal member function of a template class will be instantiated whenever it is used for the first time. But this cannot be done for the virtual member function as it can be accessed through a base class pointer. Does this mean that virtual member functions will be instantiated as soon as the template class is instantiated? If not, when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`14.7.1/9` in C++03:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

It is implementation defined.

But usually when a template class is instantiated all member for the new class type are generated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard 14.6.4.1/4:

> If a virtual function is implicitly
>   instantiated, its point of
>   instantiation is immediately following
>   the point of instantiation of its
>   enclosing class template
>   specialization.

Comment: He wants to know whether the function is instantiated or not. Not where the instantiation is put to.